# How do you trim empty spaces in number?

Tags: javascript, trim

```
    var a = "12334   ";
```

I have tried `a.trim()` and also `a.replace(/\s/g, "")` but those works for string, do we have any method to trim empty spaces for a number.

I create a filter in angular 2 which filters data set and displays results on UI.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterNumber',
  pure:false
})
export class FilterNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, searchNumber: any): string {
    if (!searchNumber) return items;
    return items.filter(function(item){
      if(item.party.trim().startsWith(searchNumber)){
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  }

}
```

item.party has value = "01234   "and when i search with 0 , i see below error

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null"

Comment: `a` is a string, not a number.

Comment: number doesn't have empty spaces.

Comment: Your premise appears to be flawed

Comment: Call `parseInt()` after you trim, then you'll get a number.

Comment: Or simply `+a` will do

Comment: @Barmar: You can even parse without trimming first.

Comment: So what did you try exactly? my guess is you did not reassign the value back to the variable and expected it to.

Comment: @Barmar use Number(number) instead of parseInt, IE for exemple parseInt in base 8...

Comment: @OptimusPrime Show what you actually tried in the question.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Number remove spaces in a String Number

Comment: .parseInt() is not a function

Comment: Okay, that edit changes everything. The problem isn't anything to do with trimming or strings or numbers. `item.party` is null and that's why it's failing.

Comment: @herohtar when i debug item.party has valu of  "012234    "

Comment: @OptimusPrime `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null` says otherwise.

Comment: Sorry @Herohtar you were right, its returning null , so i added if condition where if results arenull, return null else return numbers starting with searchNumber

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is a string and not a number to make it a number use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. Parsing the string into a number will inherently remove spaces.

```js
var a = "12334 ";
var number = parseInt(a);
console.log(number);
```